# Jenkins not Finding CVS on Solaris

Tags: jenkins, solaris, cvs

I'm trying to pull from a CVS repository from Jenkins on a Solaris box.  Jenkins is running under Tomcat and CVS is on the same machine as Jenkins and Tomcat.  When I try to set up a Jenkins job that pulls from CVS it fails with the following stack trace:

```
Building in workspace /home/tomcat/.jenkins/jobs/compile xml/workspace
cvs checkout -P -D 23 May 2013 15:49:46 -0800 -d workspace xml 
ERROR: CVS Authentication failed: Connection error
org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.AuthenticationException: Connection error
at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.LocalConnection.openConnection(LocalConnection.java:102)
at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.LocalConnection.open(LocalConnection.java:145)
at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.Client$1.run(Client.java:374)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cvs": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:328)
at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.LocalConnection.openConnection(LocalConnection.java:95)
... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
... 7 more
ERROR: Cvs task failed
```

It looks to me that Jenkins can't find cvs.  When I log in as tomcat and type cvs, the command works.  If I create a job in Jenkins and run the cvs command from the shell task, the command works.  If I echo environment variables, such as PATH or CVSROOT, I get the expected results.

Where does Jenkins look for cvs?  How can I set its path so it can see cvs?

-Update-

This looks similar: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12633 but I have cvs installed on the server

Comment: OK, I think I have a good idea of the cause - looking at the System Properties in the Manage Jenkins menu, I can see that under Environment Variables that PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin  This must be changeable...

Comment: passing -DPATH=/a/path/including/cvs to CATALINA_OPTS before starting tomcat does not work, it does update the CATALINA_OPTS environment variable, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being that Jenkins was getting its path from tomcat and tomcat was not getting the same path as the tomcat user (I assume because I'm starting tomcat as a service).  I solved this by adding the following to the beginning of catalina.sh

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/cvs
export PATH
```